# Node registration form block - hide if registered

Tags: nodes

I'm using "Node registration: this page's form" block, but I want to hide it when user has registered for this node already. I know i should use **'If' statement** but i don't know what condition to use.

Answer (score 0):

Node registration not providing a function in it's API for that, however you could include the "node_registration\includes\node_registration.api.inc" file and use their internal function that the module use to check for user access for  a specific node.

```
// Include the file
    module_load_include('inc', 'node_registration', 'includes/node_registration.api');


 if (_node_registration_user_registered($node, $account)) {
    //do something
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need function like this for Node Registration module to check if user has registered for specific node, if yes then hide the form. Your code is checking if user is logged on site.

Comment: oops, sorry, I will update my answer